# Compare 2 entries in a List

Tags: scala, mapping

Each line of the file is used to construct a map entry with the stock symbol as the key, and a list of integers as the value. The type of the structure is Map[String, List[Int]]. 
Currently my system can search for a single entry in the list and display different results for it. How would I compare 2 in the list though?
How would I compare 2 items in this list? Please find my code below that I currently have, I appreciate that I'm supposed to supply code for you to evaluate but I am not sure how to start this one. Any and every help appreciated.

```
/**
  * Created by Andre on 10/11/2016.
  */
import scala.io.Source
import scala.io.StdIn.readInt
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
import scala.util.Try

object StockMarket extends App {

  // *******************************************************************************************************************
  // application logic

    // read data from file
  val mapdata = readFile("data.txt")
  // print data to check it's been read in correctly
  //println(mapdata)

  // define menu options as a Map of actions
  // for each menu item:
  // key is an Int, the value that will be read from the input
  // value is a function () => Boolean, i.e. no params and returns Boolean
  val actionMap = Map[Int, () => Boolean](1 -> handleOne, 2 -> handleTwo, 3 -> handleThree, 4 -> handleFour, 5 -> handleFive, 6 -> handleSix, 8-> handleEight)

  // loop to read input and invoke menu option
  // uses function readOption to show menu and read input
  // uses function menu to invoke menu action
  // will terminate if menu returns false
  var opt = 0
  do {
    opt = readOption
  } while (menu(opt))



  // *******************************************************************************************************************
  // FUNCTIONS FOR MENU

  // shows menu and reads input
  def readOption: Int = {
    println(
      """|Please select one of the following:
        |  1 - show All stock levels
        |  2 - Show Selected Stock Level
        |  3 - Show Highest Stock Level
        |  4 - Show Lowest Stock Level
        |  5 - Show Current Stock Level
        |  6 - Show Average Stock Level
        |  8 - quit""".stripMargin)
    readInt()
  }

  // invokes selected menu option
  // finds corresponding function to invoke in action map using get
  // pattern matching used as get returns an Option
  def menu(option: Int): Boolean = {
    actionMap.get(option) match {
      case Some(f) => f()
      case None =>
        println("Sorry, that command is not recognized")
        true
    }
  }

  // handlers for menu options
  def handleOne(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowPoints(currentPoints)
    true
  }

  def handleTwo(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowPointsForStock(allStockLevel)
    true
  }

  def handleThree(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowSingleDataStock(highestStockLevel)
    true
  }

  def handleFour(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowSingleDataStock(lowestStockLevel)
    true
  }

  def handleFive(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowSingleDataStock(currentStockLevel)
    true
  }

  def handleSix(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowSingleDataStock(averageStockLevel)
    true
  }

  def handleEight(): Boolean = {
    println("selected quit") // returns false so loop terminates
    false
  }





  // *******************************************************************************************************************
  // UTILITY FUNCTIONS
  //GETS THE DATA FROM THE DATA.TXT
  def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
    processInput(Source.fromFile(filename).getLines)
  }
  def processInput(lines: Iterator[String]): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
    Try {
      lines.foldLeft(Map[String, List[Int]]()) { (acc, line) =>

        val splitline = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList
        acc.updated(splitline.head, splitline.tail.map(_.toInt))
      }
    }.getOrElse {
      println("Sorry, an exception happened.")
      Map()
    }
  }





  // *******************************************************************************************************************
  // FUNCTIONS THAT INVOKE ACTION AND INTERACT WITH USER
  // each of these functions accepts user input if required for an operation,
  // invokes the relevant operation function and displays the results

  def mnuShowPoints(f:() => Map[String,List[Int]]) = {
    f() foreach {case (x,y) => println(s"$x: $y")}
  }
//Returns a list value
  def mnuShowPointsForStock(f: (String) => (String,List[Int])) = {
    print("Stock > ")
    val data = f(readLine)
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2}")
  }

// Returns a single result, not a list
  def mnuShowSingleDataStock(f: (String) => (String,Int)) = {
    print("Stock > ")
    val data = f(readLine)
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2}")
  }

  //functionality to find the last tail element, the "Current" stock price
  def findLast(list:List[Int]) = list.last


  //Function to find the average
  def average(list:List[Int]): Double = list.sum.toDouble / list.size



    // *******************************************************************************************************************
  // OPERATION FUNCTIONS
  // each of these performs the required operation on the data and returns
  // the results to be displayed - does not interact with user

  def currentPoints():Map[String,List[Int]] = {
    // sort map by value in descending order -
    ListMap(mapdata.toSeq.sortWith(_._1 < _._1):_*)
  }


  def allStockLevel(team: String): (String, List[Int]) =
    (team, mapdata.get(team).getOrElse(List.empty))


  //Shows Highest Stock
  def highestStockLevel(stock: String): (String, Int) =
    (stock, mapdata.get(stock).map(_.max).getOrElse(0))

  //Shows the Lowest Stock
  def lowestStockLevel(stock: String): (String, Int) =
  (stock, mapdata.get(stock).map(_.min).getOrElse(0))


  //Show last element in the list, most current
  def currentStockLevel (stock: String): (String, Int) = {
    (stock, mapdata.get (stock).map(findLast(_)).getOrElse(0))
  }

  //Show last element in the list, most current
  def averageStockLevel (stock: String): (String, Int) = {
    (stock, mapdata.get (stock).map(average(_).toInt).getOrElse(0))
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edited*

As requested in the comment.

"for instance "SK1" and then another value, "SK2" and this will compare the 2 lists and return which is larger"

```
def largestList(a: String, b: String): Option[List[Int]] = {
  (map.get(a), map.get(b)) match {
    case (Some(alist), Some(blist)) => Some(List(alist, blist).maxBy(_.size))
    case _ => None
  }
}

val map = Map("stock1" -> List(1, 2), "stock2" -> List(3, 4, 5))

scala> largestList("stock1", "stock2")
res24: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(3, 4, 5))
```

*Old answer*

I assume that given a map `Map[String, List[Int]]` you want to search the map using values in the value (List[Int])

for example if you want to get key, value pair with value containing two number 1, 2 then do

```
map.filter { case (k, v) => v.exists(Set(1, 2)) }
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val map = Map("stock1" -> List(1, 2), "stock2" -> List(3, 4, 5))
map: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map("stock1" -> List(1, 2), "stock2" -> List(3, 4, 5))

scala> map.filter { case (k, v) => v.exists(Set(3, 4))}
res20: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map("stock2" -> List(3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: that is a helpful answer, however I need the user to be able to input a key value, for instance "SK1" and then another value, "SK2" and this will compare the 2 lists and return which is larger